# How to set RenderState in DirectX11?

Tags: directx-11

How Do I set a renderState in DirectX11?

device->SetRenderState() doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple render states in DirectX11:

- Blend State - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476349.aspx
- Depth Stencil State - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476375.aspx
- Rasterizer State - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476580.aspx
- Sampler State - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff476588.aspx

Which one do you need?

Answer (score 0):

These enumerations may be what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476152(v=vs.85).aspx