# What is the DirectX 11 equivalent of dev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, value);

Tags: comparison, alpha, directx-11, directx-9

I had a good search before starting here, this question:

[How to set RenderState in DirectX11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543477/how-to-set-renderstate-in-directx11)

is far too general; in studying the first answer, I suspect I need the Blend State, but it's not obvious how to set up an alpha comparison.

And searching stack overflow for D3DRS_ALPHAREF produced only seven other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=D3DRS_ALPHAREF none of which are even remotely close.

I'm using this for a program that does a two pass render to transition from one image to a second.  I have a control texture that is the same size as the textures I'm rendering, and is single channel luminance.

The last lines of my pixel shader are:

```
// Copy rgb from the source texture
out.color.rgb = source.color.rgb;
// copy alpha from the control texture.
out.color.a = control.color.r;
return out;
```

Then in my render setup I have:

```
DWORD const reference = static_cast<DWORD>(frameNum);
D3DCMPFUNC const compare = pass == 0 ? D3DCMP_GREATEREQUAL : D3DCMP_LESS;
m_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAREF, reference);
m_pd3dDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHAFUNC, compare);
```

Where frameNum is the current frame number of the transition: 0 through 255.

-- Edit -- For those not intimately familiar with this particular capability of DirectX 9, the final stage uses the compare function to compare the alpha output from the pixel shader with the reference value, and then it actually draws the pixel iff the comparison returns a true value.

The net result of all this is that the luminance level of the control texture controls how early or late each pixel changes in the transition.

So, how exactly do I do this with DirectX 11?

Yes, I realize there are other ways to achieve the same result, passing frameNum to a suitably crafted pixel shader could get me to the same place.

That's not the point here, I'm not looking for an alternative implementation, I am looking to learn how to do alpha comparisons in DirectX 11, since they have proven a useful tool from time to time in DirectX 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are moving from Direct3D 9 to Direct3D 11, it is useful to take a brief stop at what changed in Direct3D 10. This is covered in detail on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205073.aspx). One of the points in that article is:

> **Removal of Fixed Function**
>
> It is sometimes surprising that even in a Direct3D 9 engine that fully exploits the programmable pipeline, there remains a number of areas that depend on the fixed-function (FF) pipeline. The most common areas are usually related to screen-space aligned rendering for UI. It is for this reason that you are likely to need to build a FF emulation shader or set of shaders which provide the necessary replacement behaviors.
>
> This documentation contains a white paper containing replacement shader sources for the most common FF behaviors (see Fixed Function EMU Sample). Some fixed-function pixel behavior including alpha test has been moved into shaders.

**IOW:** You do this in a programmable shader in Direct3D 10 or later.

Take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and in particular the [AlphaTestEffect](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/AlphaTestEffect) (implemented in this [cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/AlphaTestEffect.cpp) and [shader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/Shaders/AlphaTestEffect.fx) file).